# Are there any Meta Knowledge bank available?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, model-selection, meta-learning

What resources do you use to learn meta knowledge ?
By meta knowledge, I mean generalized information that will help us take more informed decisions when working on a problem later.

Example of meta knowledge:

- Lots of time series data ? Build a CNN
- Limited in time and want to get quick insights from a dataset ? Try Random forests.
- Continuous data and supervised learning ? Do a regression.

I thought people would have build quiz-like applications to help determine good algorithm candidates to test depending on a set of known conditions.
I found "Algorithm selection" on google and the [Algorithm selection literature summary](https://larskotthoff.github.io/assurvey/), but this doesn't summarize and dumb down the information for the larger public.

The goal is for me to learn useful information that'll allow me to pick algorithms and study them in details only when I really need them, instead of randomly trying many algorithms in hope one will give me better results.